# Crashlytics for jni code in Java Application

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I use crashlytics for crash reporting in my Android application. My application has  native library. If I have exception on Java code then I have report. If I have crash in native library then I haven't crash report.   How can I catch exceptions in native code for Crashlytics? What are the solutions ?
Help me, please.